# Como autenticar uma aplicação javascript (browser) em uma API PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, login, oauth2

Pessoal,

 Estou querendo desenvolver uma API PHP (Laravel) para consumi-la tanto no meu SITE (angular), quanto nos aplicativos mobile que ainda vou desenvolver. Porém, estou com problemas para implementar uma autenticação segura que permita atualizar o tempo da sessão do usuário.

Já fiz uma pesquisa e notei que o pessoal recomenda utilizar OAUTH 2 com grant type PASSWORD ou o IMPLICIT. Porém, como é uma aplicação javascript não posso deixar o client_secret disponível, inviabilizando o grant type PASSWORD. EM contrapartida também não poderia utilizar o grant type IMPLICIT, por conta da ausência do REFRESH_TOKEN (que também precisa de passar client_secret).

Não consigo pensar em uma solução para o problema e conto com o apoio da comunidade para encontrar uma solução.

Obs: Apenas as aplicações desenvolvidas por mim podem acessar os recursos da API.

Comment: Você conhece o JWT (JSON Web Tokens)? Recomendo que dê uma pesquisada, parece que daria certo para seu projeto

Comment: Pode de ajudar: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

Comment: Com o lançamento do Laravel 5.3, ficou muito mais fácil, como o colega acima citou você acha tudo que precisa no manual.

Comment: Mas... se você preferir seguir seu próprio caminho, recomendo duas bibliotecas que eu uso a muito tempo:

JWT - https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth e
Guzzle, PHP HTTP client - https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle